building qpdf with cmake under microsoft visual 2022 failed
I'm trying to build qpdf latest version for windows using visual 2022. Build failed with message:
1> [CMake] CMake Error at libqpdf/CMakeLists.txt:192 (message):
1> [CMake]   libjpeg not found

failing cmake part is like below:
if(NOT EXTERNAL_LIBS)
  pkg_check_modules(pc_libjpeg libjpeg)
  if(pc_libjpeg_FOUND)
    list(APPEND dep_include_directories ${pc_libjpeg_INCLUDEDIR})
    list(APPEND dep_link_directories ${pc_libjpeg_LIBDIR})
    list(APPEND dep_link_libraries ${pc_libjpeg_LIBRARIES})
    set(JPEG_INCLUDE ${pc_libjpeg_INCLUDEDIR})
  else()
    find_path(LIBJPEG_H_PATH jpeglib.h)
    find_library(LIBJPEG_LIB_PATH jpeg)
    if(LIBJPEG_H_PATH AND LIBJPEG_LIB_PATH)
      list(APPEND dep_include_directories ${LIBJPEG_H_PATH})
      list(APPEND dep_link_libraries ${LIBJPEG_LIB_PATH})
      set(JPEG_INCLUDE ${LIBJPEG_H_PATH})
    else()
      message(SEND_ERROR "libjpeg not found")
      set(ANYTHING_MISSING 1)
    endif()
  endif()
endif()

how can I change cmake to add path to libjpeg? I build it properly in different folder.
--
KJ
I already search forum but didn't find answer

ok, I solved this issue by specifying exact paths as below:
set (LIBJPEG_H_PATH "C:/workspace/jpegsr9f/jpeg-9f/include/")
set (LIBJPEG_LIB_PATH "C:/workspace/jpegsr9f/jpeg-9f/Release/Win32/jpeg")

instead of finding them like it was in original file:
find_path(LIBJPEG_H_PATH jpeglib.h)
find_library(LIBJPEG_LIB_PATH jpeg)

